# How to Integrate Botium Box with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, chatbot, webdriver-io

I want to automate my chatbot by botium. But not clear how to integrate it with selenium to test its button and conversational flow. Also, want to setup webdriverio connector and how to write its script. Can anyone provide a proper demo for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather vague question. You can find introduction tutorial in the [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/294982/E2E-Testing).
And [here](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/32145510/Run+Selenium+Grid+and+Connect+to+Botium+Box) is a tutorial how to start your own Selenium server and connect it to Botium Box.

Comment: Not able to add the select device sets for the local selenium server. I am following this (https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/32145510/Run+Selenium+Grid+and+Connect+to+Botium+Box) document, but cant registers new device sets. Please help me in this.

Comment: What happens if you try to register a new device set ?

Comment: When I select Device provider = Local selenium server, there are no components in the selected device(s).

Comment: on selecting the device provider = local selenium server, there are no active devices showing in "selected devices(s)" menu. I also add resource/LOCALSELENIUM.json file: [
    {
        "name": "Google Chrome",
        "value": {
            "type": "DESKTOP",
            "capabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Mozilla Firefox",
        "value": {
            "type": "DESKTOP",
            "capabilities": {
                "browserName": "firefox"
            }
        }
    }
]

Comment: By default, the directory to place the LOCALSELENIUM.json file is "resources" - in the Botium Box distribution, there is already one present you can use. After changing this file, pls wait for some minutes and reload the UI (hitting F5 in the browser), because there is caching involved (on server and on client).

Comment: I already perform all these steps, but nothing happens. Unable to connect local selenium server in Botium. I also waited for more than 30 min. and reload 10-15 times. MY LOCALSELENIUM.json file path is: ...\botium-box\resources\LOCALSELENIUM.json

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow Shubham!

I'll try to guide you as best I can, but note that StackOverflow is usually a place to debug a current programming issue you are facing, not a place to seek start-up advice. Read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to create a reproducible example next time.

---

1. ***WebdriverIO has stellar documentation!*** I'd start by reading the [Getting Started](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. Go through all the sections, including the initial setup, so you get more comfortable.
2. Install a WebdriverIO [Boilerplate Project](https://webdriver.io/docs/boilerplate.html) of your liking and run your first tests.

   **Example:**

   - Let's say I want to run some Mobile tests cross-browser. That means Appium, so I'm looking at [webdriverio/appium-boilerplate](https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate/) project
   - Read the README.md file! (*you ever cooked without reading the recipe first?! Me neither!*)
   - Clone the project: `git clone git@github.com:webdriverio/appium-boilerplate.git`
   - Install software dependencies: `npm install` (*or w/e other package manager you're using...*)
   - Run the test command: `npm run-script <testScript>` (*in our case, `npm run ios.sauce.rdc.app` for `npm run ios.sauce.rdc.app` for Android*)
3. ***Make use of the online resources available!*** There are a lot of great *WebdriverIO tutorials & articles* creators out there. You have to find them! I personally recommend you watch all the [WebdriverIO video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/user/medigerati) created by [Kevin Lamping](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150552/kevin-lamping). I you like Kevin's knowledgeable & friendly delivery, consider enrolling for one of his [online WebdriverIO courses](https://learn.webdriver.io/).
4. ***Seek help when you're lost!*** There's a very friendly & helpful community building up behind WebdriverIO. Tap into that resource! Use the [WebdriverIO Gitter Chat](https://gitter.im/webdriverio/webdriverio) channel to find more help.

---

After setting up the boilerplate project, I'd start by writing the most basic Botium test: *use the Botium API, or some Selenium commands to generate some messages, then assert the outcome & the bot's answers*. Pretty straightforward. Break it down, step by step. Hope you make it work!

**!Note:** A boilerplate project is a project baseline, basically the minimal configuration to produce a running test framework. You can read more about boilerplate projects [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/whats-boilerplate-and-why-do-we-use-it-let-s-check-out-the-coding-style-guide-ac2b6c814ee7/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to integrate the botium tool with selenium to automate my chatbot (Button+conversational flow). I am facing issue in the register device sets. It would be much better for me if you provide a demo for this.